# Recovering a formatted drive that used to be encrypted with Bitlocker

Tags: data-recovery

I'm dual booting Windows and Mint on my laptop and I have a separate NTFS hard drive that I use to store my personal data. The hard drive used to be compatible with Mint, even though it was encrypted using Bitlocker, it worked fine. A couple of days ago, while I was attempting to format a USB stick, I accidentally formatted my hard drive instead (the drives are very close to each other in Nemo, Mint's default file manager). My drive was unlocked at the time. After formatting it, Bitlocker got removed from the drive and all of the files were vanished. I made sure to not write any data on the disk and took out the hard drive from my laptop physically.

I tried a bunch of data recovery softwares such as Stellar Data Recovery and Wise Data Recovery, but sadly, none of them could restore my files. They don't even ask me the my previous Bitlocker password, since the drive isn't locked anymore.

I also tried looking up a way to recover a drive that used to be encrypted with Bitlocker, however most of the websites contain information about methods to recover a disk for which the Bitlocker key was lost or forgotten. My case is different however, I have the Bitlocker password but the drive itself is formatted.

Is there any possibility that I can get back my data?